# Where does PHP's NumberFormatter take the locale formats from?

Tags: php, locale, currency

Where does [PHP's NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) take the locale formats from? More interested in Linux environment, if that makes any difference.

Is it compiled in, or some system resource is used? How can I view the formats for each supported locale? (`locale -c -k LC_MONETARY` doesn't seem to list/have the info on the pattern.) Are they modifiable per server?

If there is a mistake in a format, where can I report it or propose a fix? (E.g., the `lv_LV` locale has a mistake regarding the thousand separators.)

Why is the output different for HHVM – https://3v4l.org/ms1ZN ?

Comment: All I can tell from the manual is `ICU` linked in the See Also section of that page you linked to, here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/intro, I also found this in their docs.. icu-i18n Internationalization (in/i18n) library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP uses ICU library (see function `unum_formatDoubleCurrency` in [ext/intl/formatter/formatter_format.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8939c4d96b8382abe84f35e69f4f6ebd6f0f749d/ext/intl/formatter/formatter_format.c)).

ICU library, in turn, uses Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) (see http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata).

The format in the example (currency format for `lv_LV` locale), can be seen in CLDR's Survey Tool – http://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/lv/Number_Formatting_Patterns/

If there was a bug, it could be reported at http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/newticket or edited in the Survey Tool by an account acquired in this contact form: http://www.unicode.org/reporting.html

But, in the current case, there was no bug.

The format of PHP does not match CLDR data probably because of the `libicu` version (and its CLDR version) that is installed on the particular computer/server, or a specific data file being used (`icudatl.dat`, see http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata). At the moment (2018-09), the latest `libicu`/data version is 62 (see http://site.icu-project.org/home) and the latest CLDR version is 34 (see http://cldr.unicode.org/).

If `icu-devtools` is installed, running `icuinfo` would display what `libicu` and `CLDR` versions are being used. In my case: `<param name="version">55.1</param>[..]<param name="cldr.version">27.0.1</param>`

There are two alternatives given for the currency format in `lv_LV`, HHVM apparently uses the other, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to be answered if it is not documented in the official docs. However lets have a look on the `NumberFormatter` implementation of PHP: https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/8939c4d96b8382abe84f35e69f4f6ebd6f0f749d/ext/intl/formatter

If you are good in C you may find the correct place I did not find it instantly (if one of us does lets replace this part of the answer).

However as far as I understand the code the correct formats are retrieved from **the intl package** (=internationalization package, http://php.net/manual/de/book.intl.php). `NumberFormatter` itself is part of it.

In case you find a real bug you can propose a fix at the official PHP Bug reporting site regarding the intl package (https://bugs.php.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the PHP source. The formatting is done by a function external to PHP – `unum_formatDoubleCurrency`, coming from `libicu`.