# PHP NumberFormatter::CURRENCY displays USD as abbreviation instead of as symbol in my locale

Tags: php, numberformatter

Another problem in [the PHP NumberFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter) for my language and locale (bg_BG, Bulgaria): the Bulgarian textual abbreviation for USD is displayed instead of the USD symbol ($). Example: `16,32 щ.д.` instead of `16,32 $`.

I instantiate the NumberFormatter class the standard way:

```
$curr = new NumberFormatter('bg_BG', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
```

I then print money-related stuff like this:

```
echo $curr->formatCurrency($amount, $currency);
```

When the currency is EUR, the euro symbol is displayed as expected, e.g. `49,47 €`. When the currency is my own, the BGN, the textual abbreviation `л.в.` is displayed because we don't have a currency symbol for our currency.

It was the standard to display the textual abbreviation `щ.д.` for the USD until the late 1990s but things have changed since then.

I'm not sure if I can report this issue to the PHP team or if they'd care, so I'd like to be able to use a custom fix. But after a couple of hours of reading, I'm still clueless about forcing PHP to use the symbol instead of the text.

If I add this:

```
$curr->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '$');
```

it replaces my own currency's abbreviation `л.в.` with `$`, which is wrong.

Does anyone know how to force PHP to use the symbol instead of the abbreviation *only for USD*? (I have PHP 8.3.3 on my local server.)

Comment: How about only using `setSymbol()` when the `$currency` is USD?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, this is what I'm looking for but I'm not sure how to do it in the context of instantiating the NumberFormatter class.

Comment: Well, after the first line of code you have in your question, you could do: `if ($currency == "USD") { $curr->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '$'); }`. Assuming that `$currency` is actually "USD" when it is the US Dollar.

Comment: I mean, I can't just do `if($currency == 'USD') {$curr->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '$'); }` because I instantiate the NumberFormatter class and make changes to it (such as using NBSP instead of standard space) in my initiate file, when the currency var has not been declared yet. Also, I use different currency variables for different purposes on different pages. I don't want to have to add this condition every time I print currencies. This will add quite a few unnecessary lines of code to several pages.

Comment: OK, that complicates things slightly. It's difficult to see how, because I can't see your code. However, no matter how you look at it, if you want `USD` to change to `$` you have to change it...

Comment: You can write one [function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) for printing currencies, so you write the code in one place, instead of every time you want to print a currency.

Comment: Indeed, it's complicated. I was hoping I could make this fix once, just like I did this: `$num->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, '&#160;');` and then it doesn't matter where I print a number, a NBSP is printed. True, I could write a function – but I switched to the NumberFormatter class precisely because I wanted to use PHP's built-in functionality instead of coding my own. Little did I know it was so flawed with respect to my language and locale (it won't format thousands correctly, either). I've now submitted a bug report. Let's see if anyone pays attention to it.

Comment: Build-in function are fine, if they do what you want. Often however, we want something slightly different, and that's when we write our own functions. There's nothing wrong with either approach.

Comment: The locale currency formatting doesn't actually come from PHP but from a different project, there is a good explanation in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52207262/where-does-phps-numberformatter-take-the-locale-formats-from

Comment: @Matt, I found this out later, thanks. I even received a reply from a PHP dev asking me to upgrade ICU and then check again.

Comment: how do you differentiate USD from any other $ currency like AUD or CAD? The reason it doesn't let you use $ is because there are too many 'dollar' currencies on Earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't use $ because too many currencies use dollar, how would you tell USD from AUD, or CAD? but if you still want to force it you can override the methods like in my example below.

see this example in action [here at 3val](https://3v4l.org/EUMJg)

```php
<?php

class BulgarianUSDollarSignFormatter extends NumberFormatter
{
    public function formatCurrency(float $amount, string $currency): string|false
    {
        return str_replace('щ.д.', '$', parent::formatCurrency($amount, $currency));
    }
}

$curr = new BulgarianUSDollarSignFormatter('bg_BG', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$amount = '5665.25';

$currency = 'USD';
echo $curr->formatCurrency($amount, $currency).PHP_EOL;
$currency = 'EUR';
echo $curr->formatCurrency($amount, $currency).PHP_EOL;
$currency = 'BGN';
echo $curr->formatCurrency($amount, $currency).PHP_EOL;
$currency = 'AUD';
echo $curr->formatCurrency($amount, $currency).PHP_EOL;
```

outputs

```
5 665,25 $
5 665,25 €
5 665,25 лв.
5 665,25 AUD
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you're right that the $ symbol is used by other currencies as well. However, this is not so in Bulgaria(n). In Bulgarian, the $ symbol is only used to refer to the USD. Other dollar currencies are represented by the codes.

Comment: yay so my answer is suitable? I would just call the subclass `NumFmt` to save your keyboard  but this kind of thing always bights me down the line when I realize I need more classes 

Comment: interesting that `$currency = '$';` doesn't work.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work. I just tested it. It still shows "щ.д.".

Comment: you mean using '$' doesn't work yeah? because the example works: https://3v4l.org/EUMJg

Comment: When I click the example link, I see "Server not found".

Comment: @cheeseus try again? it works for me https://3v4l.org/EUMJg maybe it was down or your internet proxy doesn't allow viewing 3v4l.org